# Trying to display an X using C and a Matrix, but something isnt right

Tags: c

im trying to display an X out of the number 5 using a Matrix.
The amount of rows should be adjustable.

(Im scaning "n", and the amount of rows is 2n+1).

My issue is that either my math is wrong or i did something else incorrectly.

The 2 things that seem to not be right are: The number 5 is displayed in every cell of the matrix, not just those where i want them, and those cells that should be empty to display an X are not empty.

Here is my code

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned int i,j,m,n;
    printf("Das X erstreckt sich auf 2n+1 Zeilen. Geben sie n an. \n n = ");
    scanf("%u",&n);
    m = 2*n+1;
    int a[m][m];

    for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
            a[i][j] = 5;
            a[i][m-j-1] = 5;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What to you mean by "Trying to display X out of the number 5" ?. Do you mean you want to assign every element of the matrix to 5? You said there should be 2n + 1 rows, but how many columns? In your code you are trying to build a matrix with 2n + 1 rows and 2n + 1 columns. Make sure that's what you've intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your current loop, i.e.

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
        a[i][j] = 5;      // Assign 5
        a[i][m-j-1] = 5;  // Assign 5
    }
}
```

simply write 5 into every matrix element.

However, you want an X (which I assume is a cross made up by the diagonals).
So you need an `if` statement to tell when the position is at one of the diagonals. Further you a "neutral" value to put in elements that are not part of the diagonals.

The diagonal from upper-left to lower-right corner is given by:

```
`i == j` // Examples for m=5: (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)
```

The diagonal from upper-right to lower-left corner is given by:

```
`i == m-j-1` // Examples for m=5: (0,4), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (4,0)
```

Putting it together you get:

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
        if (i == j || i == (m-j-1))
        {
            // (i,j) is on one of the diagonals
            a[i][j] = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            // (i,j) is NOT on one of the diagonals
            a[i][j] = 0;  // Use 0 as neutral
        }
    }
}
```

**output for n = 2**

```
5   0   0   0   5   
0   5   0   5   0   
0   0   5   0   0   
0   5   0   5   0   
5   0   0   0   5
```

BTW:

If you don't want a "neutral" value as a number, change your `int` matrix to a `char` matrix so that you can use space as neutral value and then get:

```
5               5   
    5       5       
        5           
    5       5       
5               5
```

Comment: The first half of your explanation is convincing. The goal of this exercise is however obviously to teach "patterns" to the students. Hence I think the answer would be better if you would explain the condition `if (i == j || i == (m-j-1))`, because that is the core of OPs obstacle.

Comment: @Yunnosch Added some additional explanation

Comment: Nice, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    unsigned int m;
    do
    {
         printf("Das X erstreckt sich auf 2n+1 Zeilen. Geben sie n an. \n n = ");
         scanf("%d",&m);
    }while(m<3);//to get the display of pattern more Regular

    char a[m][m];
    
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            if(i==j||i==m-j-1)
            {
                a[i][j] = '5';
                a[i][j] = '5';
            }
            else
            {
                a[i][j]=' ';
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nDisplay the pattern :\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%c \t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

for example: m=5

```
   5                5
       5        5   
           5        
       5        5   
   5                5
```

when **i==j** ,this cases will fill with the caracter '5' (**Main Diagonal**)

```
a[0][0]='5';
a[1][1]='5';
a[2][2]='5';(The same case as Antidiagonal)
a[3][3]='5';
a[4][4]='5';
```

when **i==(m-j-1)**,this cases will fill with the caracter '5' (**Antidiagonal**)

```
a[0][4]='5';
a[1][3]='5';
a[2][2]='5';(The same case as Main Diagonal)(i==j)
a[3][1]='5';
a[4][0]='5';
```